# Attaching detached entries with same key

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, code-first

I am using Code First Entity Framework 4.1. The two entities that I am using are "State" and "User". Each State entry has a "CreatedBy" User and "ModifiedBy" User properties as given below.

```
public class State {
    public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual User ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

The User entity doesn't have any back reference to State entity, that is State => User is "Unidirectional".

The problem occurs when there is a detached State entity which has same "CreatedBy" and "ModifiedBy" User properties. When I try to attach State Entity to the dbContext, the EntityFramework complains that duplicate entry found by ObjectStateManager. I was looking for a simple solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to check if a `User` with the same key is already in the context and if yes, replace the detached `User` references in your `State` entity by the objects which are attached to the context. Say, `state` is the new `State` entity to attach:

```
if (state.CreatedBy != null)
{
    var attachedCreatedBy = context.ChangeTracker.Entries()
        .Where(e => e.Entity is User
                 && e.Cast<User>().Entity.Id == state.CreatedBy.Id)
        .Select(e => e.Entity)
        .SingleOrDefault();

    if (attachedCreatedBy != null)
        state.CreatedBy = attachedCreatedBy;
}

if (state.ModifiedBy != null)
{
    var attachedModifiedBy = context.ChangeTracker.Entries()
        .Where(e => e.Entity is User
                 && e.Cast<User>().Entity.Id == state.ModifiedBy.Id)
        .Select(e => e.Entity)
        .SingleOrDefault();

    if (attachedModifiedBy != null)
        state.ModifiedBy = attachedModifiedBy;
}

context.States.Attach(state); // now it should not throw an exception anymore
```

Well, I would not call this a "simple solution" though. But I don't know another one. If you had foreign key properties `CreatedById` and `ModifiedById` in `State` it would become easier. You could just set the navigation properties `CreatedBy` and `ModifiedBy` to `null` and only set the foreign key properties to the Ids of the related users.